# Create network graph from contiguous polygons in KML, or PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, kml, network, graph

I am using Postgres 9.5 and PostGIS. I have a table with a `geometry` field. This table has about 200 rows, in each of which the `geometry` field contains a Polygon.

I would now like to derive an undirected network graph from these rows, in which row is a node, and there is an edge between them if they share a boundary.

Is it possible to derive this somehow?

I also have the data in KML form, if that helps, and I think NetworkX can accept shapefiles.

Comment: Here's a start: `SELECT a.code, b.code FROM frontend_pct a, frontend_pct b WHERE a.code != b.code AND ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) < 0.1;` gets me a pairwise list of all polygons that border each other. (I think. 0.1 was chosen fairly arbitrarily and I'm not sure what units it's in.)